# black image using cvScalar method

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm little confused about the alpha values in OpenCV is't from 0-1 or 0-255?
I'm trying to change it using `cvScalar(0;0;0;0.5)` but it gives me a black image.

Comment: 0-255,  try 255,255,255for white

Comment: thanks it's correct, but i have another question what if i want to change the alpha channel in Iplimage i tried using Iplimage.alphaChannel(int arg) but i'm not sure that this method can change the alpha i'm not seeing a diffrence

Comment: First, alphaChannel of IplImage  is ignored by OpenCV (IplImage is format inherited from IPP. not all fields are actually used). Second, IplImage / cvScalar were deprecated years ago. You really shouldn't use them. Use Mat and Scalar instead.